# QPrinter PDF output is tiny

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a page set up in PYQT5 Designer, when opened normally on the screen it looks god so I tried to save to PDF.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog, QWidget, QMainWindow, QComboBox, 
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter

from export_pdf_ui import *
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.export()
    def export(self):
        printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
        printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
        printer.setOutputFileName("test.pdf")
        printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter.A4)
        printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
        printer.setFullPage(True)
        self.ui.centralwidget.render(printer)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

It works fine and outputs a PDF file, but the content is tiny and in the corner and you can't really read it even when fully zoomed in. How do I make it fill the whole page? or is it a design issue? it looks good on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating the printer with **QPrinter::ScreenResolution** rather than **QPrinter.HighResolution**.

I had a similar problem printing a QTextDocument to a physical printer which I created with QPrinter::HighResolution. If I called QTextDocument::setPageSize to eliminate page numbers, the output on paper would be about 50mm wide. I don't know if you are running into the same issue, but for me, the final piece of my puzzle was the resolution I created the QPrinter object with.